# Is accessing a variable of type sig_atomic_t with pointer atomic

Tags: c, linux, pointers, atomic

I want to have a hash table where access to every element should be atomic and I don't want to use locks. Can I use pointers to refer variables of type sig_atomic_t?

Answer (score 1):

No. `sig_atomic_t` is for signal handlers, it doesn't do anything to make values visible to other CPU's or to impose any ordering of memory accesses. C1x and C++0x have new atomic types (`<stdatomic.h>` for C1x).